# CSS buttons align for all divs except the last one

Tags: html, css

I want to display all buttons aligned to fill full div `width`, except for the last one. My code is below, but the last div is short and is expanding full width, I don't want this for the last one.

**NOTE: The buttons are dynamically generated.**

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  background-color: #cec;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#1 - A LONG TEXT GOES HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#2 - ANOTHER LONG TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#3 - SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#4 - SHORT TEXT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#5 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#6 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.button:last-child {max-width: max-content;}` - should work just fine.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Great! This is works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping put it as an Answer and I'll vote as accepted answer!

Comment: Thanks glad to hear that its all working for you. I have added an answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-class to target the last element only of you button class.

```
.button:last-child {
  max-width: max-content;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  background-color: #cec;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.button:last-child {
  max-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#1 - A LONG TEXT GOES HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#2 - ANOTHER LONG TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#3 - SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#4 - SHORT TEXT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#5 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#6 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have #6 and #7 as "short", I did a test and #6 is larger than #7 (if both are at the same "line")... can you help me?

Comment: @vrec Hi sure happy to help. If you want 6 and 7 both not to fill the width then you can use `.button:last-child, :nth-last-child(2) {}` - this should work for both 6 and 7. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have separate classes for the short ones.

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  background-color: #cec;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.short {
  max-width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#1 - A LONG TEXT GOES HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#2 - ANOTHER LONG TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#3 - SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#4 - SHORT TEXT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button short"><a href="#">#5 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button short"><a href="#">#6 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the buttons are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :last-child selector, it matches every element that is the last child of its parent.

```css
.button:last-child
```

Or you can also use nth-last-child(1) because nth-last-child(1) equal to last-child selector

```css
.button:nth-last-child(1)
```